# Is there any difference between A a; and A a = A()?

Tags: c++

Is there any difference between `A a`; and `A a = A()`?
Here `A` is a class.

Answer (score 6):

There is a formal difference between *direct initialization* syntax

```
A a;
```

and *copy initialization* syntax

```
A a = A();
```

in that the latter allows a call of the `A` copy or move constructor, and requires that there is an accessible copy constructor or move constructor.

However, in practice that extra constructor call will be elided.

Comment: The second also results with a value-initialized object `a`, which may or may not matter, depending on `A`.